# Why is this Java 2D array not throwing IndexOutOfBoundException?

Tags: java, arrays

I am initializing a 2D array, specifying both number of rows and columns. I expected it to throw an error if I insert more items than the number declared in initialization, but the code works fine.

```
static void arrayChecks(){
    int[][] arr = new int[2][2];
    arr[0] = new int[]{1,2};
    arr[1] = new int[]{3,4,5};   //adding 3 items to a 2-column row. No exception thrown
    //arr[2] = new int[]{6,7};   //throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException as expected.
    for(int[] a : arr){
        for(int i : a){
            System.out.print(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
    //output = 12345
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Java Language Specification, [§15.10.2. Run-Time Evaluation of Array Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2), [Example 15.10.2-2. Multi-Dimensional Array Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#d5e24262):

> The declaration:
>
> ```
> float[][] matrix = new float[3][3];
> ```
>
> is equivalent in behavior to:
>
> ```
> float[][] matrix = new float[3][];
> for (int d = 0; d < matrix.length; d++)
>     matrix[d] = new float[3];
> ```

This means that your code:

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][2];
arr[0] = new int[]{1,2};
arr[1] = new int[]{3,4,5};
```

Is the same as:

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][];
for (int d = 0; d < arr.length; d++)
    arr[d] = new int[2];
arr[0] = new int[]{1,2};
arr[1] = new int[]{3,4,5};
```

Or:

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][];
arr[0] = new int[2];
arr[1] = new int[2];
arr[0] = new int[]{1,2};
arr[1] = new int[]{3,4,5};
```

As you can see, the last two statements **replace** the references to the two subarrays created by the 2D array creation expression.

This means that the result is exactly the same as:

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][];
arr[0] = new int[]{1,2};
arr[1] = new int[]{3,4,5};
```

Except that you wasted time and GC creating the two subarrays.

Answer (score 10):

Java doesn't support 2D arrays in the way some languages do. It just treats them as an array of array references. These inner arrays can be reassigned to another array of any length.

The desugared version of `int[][] arr = new int[2][2];` is:

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][];
arr[0] = new int[2];
arr[1] = new int[2];
```

You can reassign `arr[1]` to any `int[]` that you want. Java allows for jagged arrays, where each inner array is a different length.

Reference - [Example 15.10.2-2. Multi-Dimensional Array Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.2)

Comment: I'm not OP, but for what it's worth, this is the first answer I immediately understood.

Comment: It would be nice in my opinion also add to your answer some references to that info, I didn't knew it...

Comment: @DamianLattenero See [The Truth About 2D Arrays](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c7/s5.html)

Comment: @DamianLattenero Reference to that info (the specification) is in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45443579/5221149)

Comment: @Henry thanks! with that it's perfect to me :), you got my plus one 4c

Answer (score 2):

`new int[]{3,4,5}` is creating a **new** array. That new array now has a length of 3.

If you instead use `int[1][2] = 5`, you will get your `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because this is editing the old array.

See [The Truth About 2D Arrays](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c7/s5.html) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you came to the java world with some background in other languages. In Java there are no multidimensional arrays. The expression `new int[2][2]` is really just a syntactic sugar of building an array of arrays row-by-row. The implication is that there is no "width" concept, every row can have it's own length. With `arr[1] = new int[]{3,4,5};` you just replaced a row with a longer one, which is (sometimes unfortunately) a valid move in the Java world. If you want to avoid accidents, don't replace whole rows, fill the array cell-by-cell:

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][2];
arr[1][0] = 3;
arr[1][1] = 4;
arr[1][2] = 5; # throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new row.
If you will debug the your code you will see that after `arr[1] = new int[]{3,4,5};`  you now have this

[image]

if you would do this instead :

```
 int[][] arr = new int[2][2];
 arr[1][3] = 1;
```

you will get your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`